# How to show nearing place in telegram bot?

Tags: php, mysql, location, bots, telegram

I create bot in telegram for showing near restaurant my bot have to button first button for inserting Geographical coordinates restaurant and my server recive lat and long and save it  i create first button and good work 
But i cant create second button for showing near restaurant this is my code 
Please help me 
Thx

```
<?php
//$json=file_get_contents('php://input');
$update = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

//main input
$message    = $update->message->text;
$chatid     = $update->message->chat->id;
$last_name  = $update->message->from->last_name;
$first_name = $update->message->from->first_name;
$usernameid = $update->message->from->username;
$latitude   = $update->message->location->latitude;
$longitude  = $update->message->location->longitude;

$text1 = "insert location";
$text2 = "show near restaurant";

$token = '';

$servername = "localhost";
$dbname     = "";
$username   = "";
$password   = "";

//$rep=json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token."/SendMessage?chat_id=".$chatid."&text=".urldecode($json)));

$reply_markup = json_encode(["keyboard"        =>
                                 [
                                     [["text" => $text1, "request_location" => true]],
                                     //[["text"=>$text1]],
                                     [["text" => $text2]],

                                 ],
                             "resize_keyboard" => true]);

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
mysqli_query($conn, 'set names "utf8"');

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: ".$conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Tehran");
$time = date("h:i:sa");

$date = date("Y/m/d");

if ($message == "/start") {

    $starttxt = "hello".$first_name." ".$last_name."how are you?"."✌️✌️✌️";
    $rep      = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token."/SendMessage?chat_id=".$chatid."&reply_markup=".$reply_markup."&text=".urldecode($starttxt)));

    $sql    = "INSERT INTO user_info (date,time,T_id,T_firstname,T_lastname,T_username) VALUES ('$date','$time','$chatid','$first_name','$last_name','$usernameid')";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
}

if ($longitude != null) {

    $rep = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token."/SendMessage?chat_id=".$chatid."&reply_markup=".$reply_markup."&text=".urldecode("long is: ".$longitude." lat is: ".$latitude)));

    $sql    = "INSERT INTO insert_location (T_id,T_username,date,time,latitude,longitude) VALUES ('$chatid','$usernameid','$date','$time','$latitude','$longitude')";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
}

if ($message == "show near restaurant") {

    $rep = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token."/SendMessage?chat_id=".$chatid."&reply_markup=".$reply_markup."&text=".urldecode($starttxt)));

    $sql = SELECT id, (3959 * acos(cos(radians(37)) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians(-122)) + sin(radians(37)) * sin(radians(latitude)))) AS distance FROM insert_location HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;

    $result = $conn->query($sql);
}

?>
```

and this image form mysql when user click on first button

[image: and this image form mysql when user click on first button]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find answer for this question in google maps api v_3 for show nearing place

```
SELECT id, latitude, longitude, ( 6371 * acos ( cos ( radians($latitude) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians($longitude) ) + sin ( radians($latitude) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM insert_location HAVING distance < 3;
```

6371 for kilometer

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean [sendVenue](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendvenue)?

BTW, I suggest use [/setinlinegeo](https://core.telegram.org/bots/inline#location-based-results) with [Venue Result](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinequeryresultvenue), it can let users choose from up to 50 results.

Comment: thx for suggesting but i don't love use /setinlinegeo i love receive location from user and send result A range of 2 km

Comment: @MasihKolahdouzan I know inline geo is not good for all situation, so please try first solution about sendVenue.